# Text area not editable/Unable to type text in text area

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development.

I have a web application written in nodejs-html-css-js.

I have a text area, but I am unable to type or insert anything. It is embedded to a slide pop up. Here is the code.

```css
.cd-panel-container h1{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 155px;
  /*display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;*/

}
.cd-panel-container h1:before {
  content:' ';
  width: 120px;
  display:block;
  border:1.5px solid #00DED4;
  border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.post-textarea textarea {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-top: 30%;
}
.cd-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*background: green;*/
}
.cd-panel-close::before, .cd-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before, .no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 28%;
  height: 87%;
  top: 7%;
  background: #33AAFF;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  margin-right: 477px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
/*@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
*/
.cd-panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 70px 5%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.cd-panel-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #424f5c;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.cd-panel-content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cd-panel from-right">
  <div class="cd-panel-container">
    <h1>New Posts</h1>
    <div class="cd-panel-content">
      <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-panel-content -->
    <div class="cd-panel-textarea">
      <textarea class="post-textarea">What's happening?..</textarea>
    </div><!--cd-panel-textarea-->
  </div> <!-- cd-panel-container -->
<!-- <button class="click-post-btn">Post</button> -->
</div> <!-- cd-panel -->
```

In the above snippet, I am able to get the text area but I am not able to edit it.

However, if I insert a new CSS snippet, nothing is visible. Here is that snippet.

```css
*::after, *::before {
  content: '';
}

a {
  color: #89ba2c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.cd-panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.6s;
}

.cd-panel::after {
  /* overlay layer */
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 0;*/
  /*left: 0;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*background: transparent;*/
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
  /*-webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;*/
  /*-moz-transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;*/
  /*transition: background 0.3s 0.3s;*/
}

.cd-panel.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0s;
}

.cd-panel.is-visible::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  /*background: #00bdff;*/
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s 0s;
  transition: background 0.3s 0s;
}

.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-1 0.6s 0.3s;
}

.cd-panel.is-visible .cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
  animation: cd-close-2 0.6s 0.3s;
}


@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-close-1 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cd-close-2 {
  0%, 50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

The problem is, I will be needing both CSS snippets for reaching my goal. 
Logic: I click a button, a slide pop up reveals with a text area. I want to type the text and the post gets saved in a calendar event.

However, I am not getting any results if I include the above attached code.

Any suggestions or solutions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: With the second snippet you cannot see anything because of .cd-panel {... visibility: hidden; ...} and your html starts with <div class="cd-panel from-right">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `position` and `z-index` properties to the textarea to ensure they stack above `.cd-panel-content`

```css
.cd-panel-container h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 155px;
  /*display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;*/
}

.cd-panel-container h1:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 120px;
  display: block;
  border: 1.5px solid #00DED4;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.post-textarea textarea {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.cd-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*background: green;*/
}

.cd-panel-close::before,
.cd-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before,
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}

.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 28%;
  height: 87%;
  top: 7%;
  background: #33AAFF;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  margin-right: 477px;
}

.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}

.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}


/*@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
*/

.cd-panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 70px 5%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.cd-panel-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #424f5c;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.cd-panel-content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}

.cd-panel-textarea {
  /* add this */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="cd-panel from-right">
  <div class="cd-panel-container">
    <h1>New Posts</h1>
    <div class="cd-panel-content">
      <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-panel-content -->
    <div class="cd-panel-textarea">
      <textarea class="post-textarea">What's happening?..</textarea>
    </div>
    <!--cd-panel-textarea-->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-panel-container -->
  <!-- <button class="click-post-btn">Post</button> -->
</div>
<!-- cd-panel -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue because you added `.cd-panel-content` with absolute position without z-index.. set `z-index:- 1` for that

```css
.cd-panel-container h1{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 155px;
  /*display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;*/
}
.cd-panel-container h1:before {
  content:' ';
  width: 120px;
  display:block;
  border:1.5px solid #00DED4;
  border-radius:2px;
  -webkit-border-radius:4px;
  -moz-border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}

.post-textarea textarea {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
  z-index: 999;
  margin-top: 30%;
}

.cd-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*background: green;*/
}
.cd-panel-close::before, .cd-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before, .no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 28%;
  height: 87%;
  top: 7%;
  background: #33AAFF;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  margin-right: 477px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
/*@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
*/
.cd-panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 70px 5%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  z-index: -1;
}
.cd-panel-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #424f5c;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.cd-panel-content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cd-panel from-right">
  <div class="cd-panel-container">
    <h1>New Posts</h1>
    <div class="cd-panel-content">
      <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
    </div> <!-- cd-panel-content -->
    <div class="cd-panel-textarea">
      <textarea class="post-textarea">What's happening?..</textarea>
    </div><!--cd-panel-textarea-->
  </div> <!-- cd-panel-container -->
<!-- <button class="click-post-btn">Post</button> -->
</div> <!-- cd-panel -->
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can make your text area editable by removing Width and height which you have set to 100% in cd-panel-content class **

```css
.cd-panel-container h1{
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 155px;
  /*display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;*/

}
.cd-panel-container h1:before {
    content:' ';
    width: 120px;
    display:block;
    border:1.5px solid #00DED4;
    border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
}


 .post-textarea textarea {
    width: 45%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    font-size: 16px;
    resize: none;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-top: 30%;
}


.cd-panel-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  /* image replacement */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*background: green;*/
}
.cd-panel-close::before, .cd-panel-close::after {
  /* close icon created in CSS */
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* this fixes a bug where pseudo elements are slighty off position */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cd-panel-close::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cd-panel-close::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before, .no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(220deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(220deg);
  transform: rotate(220deg);
}
.no-touch .cd-panel-close:hover::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.cd-panel-container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 28%;
  height: 87%;
  top: 7%;
  background: #33AAFF;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  margin-right: 477px;
}
.from-right .cd-panel-container {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.from-left .cd-panel-container {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.is-visible .cd-panel-container {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
/*@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-panel-container {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
*/
.cd-panel-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  padding: 70px 5%;
  overflow: auto;
  /* smooth scrolling on touch devices */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.cd-panel-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #424f5c;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.cd-panel-content p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-panel-content p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.6;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cd-panel from-right">
      <div class="cd-panel-container">
            <h1>New Posts</h1>
        <div class="cd-panel-content">
          <a href="#0" class="cd-panel-close">Close</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-panel-content -->
        <div class="cd-panel-textarea">
          <textarea class="post-textarea">What's happening?..</textarea>
        </div><!--cd-panel-textarea-->
       
    </div> <!-- cd-panel-container -->
    <!-- <button class="click-post-btn">Post</button> -->
   
  </div> <!-- cd-panel -->
```